# Python - Selenium webdriver not returning cookies from all domains (sub domains)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to scrape website using selenium, where an HTTP request runs on `login.example.com` to login to a site using username and password and on success, it redirects to `example.com`.

When I am trying to retrieve all cookies using Selenium Webdriver, it is missing some cookies from sub domain like `api.example.com` but **I am able to see all cookies in the Chrome browser/webdriver manually.** but selenium webdriver returning only for sub domain. i.e `api.example.com`

Here's the code.

```
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument('--log-level=3')
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
    chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    chrome_options.add_argument('user-data-dir=selenium')
    # chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
    logger.out("Starting browser...")
    driver_path = ChromeDriverManager().install()
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driver_path, options=chrome_options)
    #Login here
    driver.get('https://example.com')
    cookies = self.driver.get_cookies()
```